ERROR TypeError: this.getNativeComponent is not a function (it is undefined)
ERROR  Type Error: this .get Native Component is not a function (it is undefined) appears twice in the command line. I have managed to Identify where the problem is: In my MapScreen.js in the return section I commented out a Marker:
{ /*<Marker coordinate={{ latitude: location .latitude, longitude: location .longitude }} title="Current Location" description="This is your current location" />*/ }
...no error happens when you run the program commented. Help me to adjust the Marker so that is works and stops showing the error:
ERROR  Type Error: this .get Native Component is not a function (it is undefined)
From nowhere this problem came up because it was working fine before, then all of a sudden it says ERROR  Type Error: this .get Native Component is not a function (it is undefined).
